# How to get value of an option if i know the index - jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How to get vale of an option if i know index of that option.? .Its a list box

```
<div id="selDiv">
    <select id="opts" multiple="multiple">
            <option selected value="DEFAULT">Default</option>
            <option value="SEL1">Selection 1</option>
            <option value="SEL2">Selection 2</option>
    </select>
```

if i want to get value of index 1.(ie, SEL1).how can i do this? . and how can i make that option is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#opts').find('option').eq(1).attr('selected','selected').val();
```

And if you want to unselect the first option you would do:

```
$('#opts').find('option').eq(0).attr('selected',false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#opts').children('option').eq(1).attr('value'); 
$('#opts').children('option').eq(1).attr('selected','selected');
```